# Creating a dasboard-esque page for viewing data

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently working on a web app using .NET Core and Razor pages.
So after getting the CRUD elements pretty much sorted, the final part for me is to create a page so they can view their main data.

At the moment, their requirements for searching data would be by person and / or by project.

My initial plan is to give them two drop downs containing each of these data. And when they're happy to start the search, press a button and a SP will retrieve the data from the data base.

The bit I need help with is displaying the data. Before I was using fairly standard HTML tables in the page.

However now that the data will be refreshed and will be different based on the search parameters I'm not too sure on how to implement this.

The only way I can think of doing this is to create a API to get the data back from the DB in a JSON format and then use JavaScript functions, possibly including the data tables plugin.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our articles on [ask], and provide a [mcve] showing your code and what you have already tried so far, so we will be able to help you.

Comment: Have you seen the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which suggests that you could create a form to submit the chosen data  to controller (using `name` attribute) and return filtered data to view?

Comment: Hi Xing, apologies for the delayed response. I did take a look however I didn't notice the drop down search towards the bottom.

As it was also using LINQ, I wasn't too sure it'd be the best way.